# How does the SSL/TLS protocol determine if a certificate is expired or not?

Tags: tls, certificates, cryptography, expiration-date

I already tried googling but no luck. All search results always tell you how to check cert expiration **manually**, but that is not my question. Yes I can use OpenSSL for example, but what I am asking is how the SSL/TLS protocol does it, not how a user/human can do it.

The question:

We know that SSL/TLS handshake will fail if a certificate is expired. How does the SSL/TLS protocol determine if a certificate is expired or not? What is/are the mathematical functions being used to extract the validity date? Also to what "time reference" (or database?) does it compare the current validity date to determine if it is expired or not? Is it the time of the local machine or of some remote server or what?

Comment: The expiry date is part of the certificate. If you try to edit the expiry date in the certificate then the signature will be invalid and thus the entire certificate will also be invalid. You don't need to look anywhere else, just look at the certificate data for the expiration date.

Comment: @slebetman Yes, if we edit the expiry date then the hashes won't match. But the thing is, we DO NOT edit the expiry date. Nothing has changed on the certificate, what has changed is the current time. So, therefore, even if the current time is already past the expiry date, the hashes should still match because we did not edit anything. Right?

Comment: If the current time is past the expiry date then the certificate is expired and is no longer valid

Comment: Obviously you can set your PC clock to 1999 in order to accept old certificates but this is you deliberately setting your clock to the past. A network service or web page cannot set your clock. A locally installed program maybe can (eg. a virus) but a locally installed program can do much worse than just changing your clock.

Comment: @slebetman Yes, but my point is, the method of hash comparison cannot tell if the certificate is expired or not. Because the hashes will still match. There must be other way/method to know if the certificate is expired.

Comment: The expiry date - the expiry date is the method. See my original comment. It was always the expiry date. The hash will tell you if the expiry date is valid or has been altered.

Comment: It doesn't involve any additional protocol or any other server. The certificate itself will tell you when it expires and the certificate itself will tell you if someone attempted to alter the expiry date. It's all directly saved in the certificate file.

Comment: @slebetman Ok, thank you very much for trying to help me, I really appreciate your effort. However, as I pointed out, we do not alter the expiry date. It stays the same. Only the current time changes. That's why I can't see how we can check if cert is expired or not by just comparing the hashes, because the hashes would still match.

Comment: Comparing the date. Not the hash. The hash tell you that the date is valid. The date tell you if the certificate is expired. The date is what you compare

Comment: OK if you still really don't understand. We determine that the certificate is valid or expired by checking the expiry date that is actually part of the certificate itself (not additional data from another service) against the current time. If the current time is newer than the expiry date inside the certificate then the certificate has expired.

Answer (score 17):

> how the SSL/TLS protocol does it

The SSL/TLS protocol does not define how certificates are validated. You need to look instead [RFC 5280](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.5), which is about certificates in general. SSL/TLS just makes use of established mechanism for certificate validation.

> What is/are the mathematical functions being used to extract the validity date?

A certificate is simply a serialized data structure. The expiration date can easily be extracted when deserializing this structure. How the data structure looks like is defined in RFC 5280. The serialization method is [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1). There are many different implementations in different languages to do this.

> Also to what "time reference" (or database?) does it compare the current validity date to determine if it is expired or not? Is it the time of the local machine or of some remote server or what?

I cannot see any explicit definition which time source should be use for comparison, but I think it is obvious that it should be one which is considered the correct one by the one doing the check. Usually this means the time on the local machine, which today often gets synchronized with the actual time. But it is a common source of validation failures if the local time is way off the actual time.

Comment: "SSL/TLS just makes use of established mechanism for certificate validation." - may I ask more about this? What are those established mechanisms? Also, are those mechanisms part of the SSL/TLS handshake?

Comment: @Noob_Guy: *"What are those established mechanisms?"* - RFC 5280. *"Also, are those mechanisms part of the SSL/TLS handshake?"* - the handshake is about transporting the certificate and expecting the application to verify it. The verification itself is not part of the TLS specification. It is usually done within the time of the handshake, i.e. usually once the certificate is received. It must be done at least before exchanging application data, so it might even be done after the handshake itself has finished.

Comment: Ok thanks. Just one more clarification please.. If the cert verification is not part of SSL/TLS specification, does it mean it is optional? What happens if we dont verify the certificate? And if it is not optional, then what specification mandates it?

Comment: @Noob_Guy: from [RFC 8446 (TLS 1.3)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8446#section-1): *"The server side of the channel is always
      authenticated"*. It does not mandate certificates for this, but this is the most common way. Without server authentication the client does not know if it communicates with the intended server or some attacker impersonating the server (for example during a MITM attack)

Comment: @Noob_Guy it is optional. Most systems have an option to skip it. Web browsers make this difficult for the user to do, because it removes most of the safety provided by TLS.

Comment: Certificate validation isn't _entirely_ orthogonal to TLS/SSL. OCSP stapling is defined as an extension to TLS.

Comment: @James_pic: The full process of certificate validation is not part of SSL/TLS specification. But of course, SSL/TLS needs to provide the data needed for the validation. Transporting the OCSP response as part of OCSP stapling is one example, but transporting the certificate in the first place and using signatures based on the certificates private key is an even more obvious one.